# How to use awk to calculate the median values in column 2, when column 1 has repeated rows?

Tags: sorting, awk, multiple-columns, median

I have a file like below:

```
1 , 2.0
1 , 59.0
1 , 0.3
2 , 4.5
2 , 2.3
3 , 15.4
4 , 82.4
4 , 5.7
4 , 9.0
```

I'd like to find the median of column 2 when column 1 is repeated, desired output as below:

```
1 , 2.0
2 , 3.4
3 , 15.4
4 , 9.0
```

How could I use awk and sort to do this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way with `awk`.

#### Content of median.awk

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = " , " }
function find_med(count, med) {
    if(count == 1) {
        return med[1];
    } 
    else if(count == 2) {
        return ((med[1] + med[2]) / 2);
    } 
    else {
       return med[sprintf("%0.f",((count / 2) + 1))];
    }
}
NR>1 && $1 != seen {
    median = find_med(cnt, total);
    print seen, median;
    delete total;
    cnt = 0
}
{
    seen = $1;
    total[++cnt] = $2;
}
END {
    median = find_med(cnt, total);
    print seen, median;
}
```

#### Run it like:

```
$ awk -f median.awk <(sort -nk1,1 -k2,2 -t',' file)
1 , 2.0
2 , 3.4
3 , 15.4
4 , 9.0
```